# Background image while loading uiwebview ios is shown sometimes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I load a webpage inside my ios app. While it is loading I show a local image to avoid black screen for a while.

I use this code in viewDidLoad:

```
[myWebView setDelegate:self];
theLoadingImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myWebView.frame];


if([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] ==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){

    theLoadingImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"splash_iphone.png"];

}
else{

    theLoadingImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"splash_ipad.png"];

}





self.logoApp = theLoadingImageView;
[myWebView addSubview:theLoadingImageView];
```

And delegates added:

```
-(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)myWebView {
    NSLog(@"start");
   theLoadingImageView.hidden = NO;
}

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)myWebView {
    NSLog(@"finish");
     theLoadingImageView.hidden = YES;
}
```

But sometimes, while changing between sections of my webpage, the splash screen appears for a second and hides again.

Why is this happening? can I avoid it?

Comment: Sometimes, when you navigate the website from the UIWebView, the current loading is cancelled. Try to implemente the - (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error method to check if it is the error case.

Comment: Thats may happen when you change section the web view may start loading some data.. :)

Comment: what do you mean by "changing between sections of my webpage"?

Comment: I mean, you stay in index.html and load a new page. I am using jquery and other pages are created as "sections" with an id and to go there your href links seem like this: href="#otherPage". Well, when you click to one of those links, sometimes you see the splash screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is entirely possible that the UIWebView re-orders it's subviews (it is just a UIScrollView with subviews after all). You should try calling:

```
-(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)myWebView {
    NSLog(@"start");
    theLoadingImageView.hidden = NO;
    [myWebView bringSubviewToFront:theLoadingImageView];
}
```

Comment: It just happends while loading a determined "page" not with others. I will try your code and I will tell you what happends.

Comment: Is it possible that once the webpage has load the first time, it will always set the image to the background or hide or delete or something similar?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge it won't alter the image or visibility state of a UIImageView you created - however the web view might remove it from it's hierarchy or change the subview index as I said before. You should log myWebView.subviews at various points to see where your view is in the subview stack

Comment: I solved it. I had to delete the hidden = NO order. Doing it seems to make it light whenever it hangs